# Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map

Tags: debugging, emacs

I'm trying to remap some keys in dired like this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (require 'dired )
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") nil)))
    (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
    ))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, I get this error

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: dired-mode-map
```

Which is werid, because I should be loading in dired. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original poster has two (2) many [pun intended] closing parentheses at this point:  `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") nil)))` -- i.e., two (2) closing parentheses at the end of that line need to be eliminated.  Furthermore, I do not see a reason to set the binding to `nil` before redefining it.

The following is another way of accomplishing the same goal.  Add any additional key bindings after the `progn` statement as desired.

```
(eval-after-load "dired" '(progn
  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-o") 'other-window) ))
```

Comment: This fixes the problem. Weird that the unbalanced parentheses don't cause other errors...

Comment: I would recommend going through that user customization file and look for other problems with parentheses.  Early on in my Emacs journey, I had some missing and some extra closing parentheses that had the effect of combining several functions that should have been separate -- e.g., function number one (1) was missing a closing parentheses, and function number ten (10) [*further on down in my `.emacs` file*] had an extra closing parentheses -- thus, I had one giant function [ten in one] that of course didn't work.   :)  In that situation, the parentheses were balanced.

Comment: A possible reason for first setting `M-o` to nil is that `M-o` is a prefix key by default, and at least for some Emacs versions you need to unbind the prefix-key binding first. It never hurts to do so, in any case.

Comment: What is wrong from just having the `define-key` without the `eval-after-load`?

Comment: @user129393192 — the error message described in the question by the O.P. of this thread will occur if the library has not previously been loaded.  The question sought to resolve the problem that caused the error message.